# find month names withing for loop

Tags: vba, date

It returns only saturday, for the dates it was simple because I only needed to add a plus 1 but how to i get it to loop from 1 to 7? Also how about for the months names as well

```
Sub netprofit()

Dim dates As Date
Dim count As Integer

Dim olweekdayname As String

olweekdayname = WeekdayName(Weekday(dates))

dates = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)
For count = 2 To 366

Select Case Weekday(dates)

Case 1, 7

    Range("B" & count) = 0

    Range("C" & count) = 0

    Range("D" & count) = 0
    Range("E" & count) = olweekdayname


Case Else
    Range("C" & count) = Int((100 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
    Range("D" & count) = Range("B" & count) - Range("C" & count)
    Range("A" & count) = dates
    Range("E" & count) = olweekdayname

End Select
dates = dates + 1

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that doesnt stop it from listing only saturday for the weekday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line `olweekdayname = WeekdayName(Weekday(dates))` must be inside of the loop, otherwise `olweekdayname` will not be changed, so your updated code is below, tested, works fine.

```
Sub netprofit()
    Dim dates As Date
    Dim count As Integer
    dates = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)
    For count = 2 To 366
        Select Case Weekday(dates)
        Case 1, 7
            Range("B" & count) = 0
            Range("C" & count) = 0
            Range("D" & count) = 0
            Range("E" & count) = WeekdayName(Weekday(dates))
            Range("F" & count) = MonthName(Month(dates))
        Case Else
            Range("C" & count) = Int((100 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            Range("D" & count) = Range("B" & count) - Range("C" & count)
            Range("A" & count) = dates
            Range("E" & count) = WeekdayName(Weekday(dates))
            Range("F" & count) = MonthName(Month(dates))
        End Select
        dates = dates + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that was all I needed to do???? instead of having the name of the function all I needed to was have the actual function. darn ive got lots to learn